# How do I uninstall a service installed using install4j

Tags: install4j

My installer has a "install service" action, which installs a bundled binary as as a service. However, I can't find an "uninstall service" action despite the fact that the [manual](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/services.html) references it:

> On Windows it is expected that there is a special program that
>   installs an uninstalls the service. This is done by the "Install a
>   service" and "**Uninstall a service**" actions in install4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking for a while, if found that elsewhere in the manual (actually, the [reference](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/installerGui/availableActions.html)), under "install a service" they state that:

> "This action will be automatically reverted by the 'Uninstall files'
>   action."

So it turns out that the "uninstall a service" action doesn't exist.